# CSS Boxes Straight across

Tags: html, css

I've been having problems getting this worked out. I have three boxes on a page and I want them to all line up stright across. But the middle one is sagging.

You can find the site here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php

Right below the Header images you will see the three boxes. The middle is sagging!

The HTML Code is:

```
    <div class="wrapper margin-bot1">

    <div class="bg-3">
    <div class="indent">
    <div class="wrapper margin-bot"><img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/page1_img1.png" alt="" /><a href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/archilume-collection.html"><img style="padding-left: 34px;" src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/logo_archilume.png" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ul-1">
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Made in USA</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Expert Domestic Tech Support</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">High-end installations</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Robust features</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/archilume-collection.html">Click to Order Now!</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-3">
    <div class="indent">
    <div class="wrapper margin-bot"><img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/XLD-SLD_group_thumb.png" alt="" /><a href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/genlume-collection.html"> <img style="padding-left: 56px;" src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/GenLume-Logo.png" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ul-1">
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Quick solutions</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Turn-key applications</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Certified</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Competitive pricing</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/genlume-collection.html">Click to Order Now!</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-3">
    <div class="indent">
    <div class="wrapper margin-bot"><img title="duralume new" src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/NEw.png" alt="new" width="62" height="52" /><a href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/duralume-collection-usa.html"><img style="padding-left: 34px;" src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/duralume.gif" alt="" width="144" height="33" /></a>
    <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ul-1">
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Expert Domestic Tech Support</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Made in USA</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Custom solutions</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">On-site Engineers</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/duralume-collection-usa.html">Click to Order Now!</a></div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

The CSS Code is:

```
    @import"reset.css";@import"grid.css";

    /* Global Structure---------------------------------------- */
    .main 
    {
        width: 950px; // Reduced this to match with the parent's width
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .wrapper {width:100%; overflow:visible; position:relative;}
    .extra-wrap {overflow:hidden;}
    /*----- txt,links,lines,titles -----*/
    .fleft{float:left}
    .fright{float:right}
    .alignright{text-align:right}
    .aligncenter{text-align:center}
    .alignmiddle *{vertical-align:middle}
    .d-in-block {display:inline-block;}
    .d-block {display:block;}
    .reg {text-transform:uppercase;}
    .reg2 {letter-spacing:-1px;}
    .reg3 {letter-spacing:-2px;}
    .index {z-index:99; position:relative;}
    .rel {position:relative;}
    .color1{color:#ff2100;}
    /********************** Content ************************/

    .img-indent-l {float:left; margin:0px 12px 0px 0px;}
    .img-indent-2 {float:left; margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;}

    /*********************************boxes**********************************/
    .indent {padding:27px 20px 27px 25px;}
    .indent1 {padding:25px 15px 15px 25px;}
    .indent2 {padding:24px 15px 10px 19px;}

    .indent-left {padding-left:0px;}

    .indent-bottom {padding-bottom:18px;}
    .indent-bottom1 {padding-bottom:8px;}

    .indent-right {padding-right:0px;}

    .indent-top {padding-top:19px;}
    .indent-top1 {padding-top:39px;}

    .margin-top { margin-top:-10px;}
    .margin-top1 { margin-top:-2px;}
    .margin-top2 { margin-top:-6px;}
    .margin-top3 { margin-top:-8px;}
    .margin-top4 { margin-top:-4px;}
    .margin-top5 { margin-top:7px;}

    .margin-bot {margin-bottom:7px;}
    .margin-bot1 {margin-bottom:10px;}
    .margin-bot2 {margin-bottom:24px;}
    .margin-bot3 {margin-bottom:21px;}
    .margin-bot4 {margin-bottom:17px;}
    .margin-bot5 {margin-bottom:30px;}
    .margin-bot6 {margin-bottom:19px;}
    .margin-bot7 {margin-bottom:58px;}
    .margin-bot8 {margin-bottom:25px;}
    .margin-bot9 {margin-bottom:15px;}
    .margin-bot10 {margin-bottom:6px;}
    .margin-bot11 {margin-bottom:10px;}
    .margin-bot12 {margin-bottom:28px;}
    .margin-bot13 {margin-bottom:26px;}
    .margin-bot14 {margin-bottom:62px;}

    .margin-left {margin-left:5px; margin-left: 27px;}
    .margin-left1 {margin-left:16px;}

    .margin-right {margin-right:14px;}

    /*********************************content*************************************/
    #content {
        width:100%; 
        padding:60px 0;
        position:relative;
        background:url(../images/bg-5.gif) left top repeat-x #fff;
    }
    #page1 #content {padding-top:57px;}
    /*********************************bg's*************************************/
    .bg-1 {
        background:url(../images/bg-2.jpg) left top repeat-x;
        width:100%;
        border-top:6px solid #fff;
        height:351px;
    }
    .img {
        position:absolute;
        width:359px;
        height:582px;
        background:url(../images/page1_img.png) left top no-repeat;
        top:-113px;
        right:0;
        z-index:19;
    }
    .bg-2 {
        background:url(../images/bg-3.jpg) left top no-repeat;
        width:100%;
        height:351px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .bg-3 
    {
        overflow: visible;
        width: 33%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 270px;
        background-image: url(http://www.webstertoolbox.com/skin/frontend/default/erglighting/images/bg-4.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

    .floatstop:after {
        clear: both;
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    :first-child + html .floatstop {
        min-height: 1px;
    }
    * html .floatstop {
        height: 1%;
    }

    .bg-4 {
        background:url(../images/bg-6.png) left top no-repeat;
        height:182px;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .bg-5 {
        width:88px;
        height:215px;
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        top:-22px;
        background:url(../images/page2_img8.png) left top no-repeat;
    }
    .bg-6 {
        background:url(../images/bg-7.png) left top no-repeat;
        height:182px;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:100%;
    }

    .border-1 {border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;}
    .border-2 {border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}
    /*********************************buttons*************************************/
    .button-1 {
        display:inline-block;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:15px;
        line-height:18px;
        border-radius:17px;
        -moz-border-radius:17px;
        -webkit-border-radius:17px;
        background:url(../images/button-1-2.png) left -82px repeat-x #555;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* FF3.6 */
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* IE10 */
        background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background:         linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555);
        padding:7px 18px 10px 15px;
    }
    .button-1>span {
        display:inline-block;
        width:17px;
        height:11px;
        margin:4px 0 0 13px;
        background:url(../images/button-1.png) left top no-repeat;
        margin-left: 27px;
    }
    .button-1:hover {
        background:url(../images/button-1-2.png) repeat-x left 0 #2f2f2f;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #404040, #2f2f2f); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #404040, #2f2f2f); /* FF3.6 */
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #404040, #2f2f2f); /* IE10 */
        background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #404040, #2f2f2f); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background:         linear-gradient(top, #404040, #2f2f2f);
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .button-2 {
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:16px;
        color:#3e3e3e;
        padding:4px 13px 6px;
        border:1px solid #c9c9c9;
        border-radius:15px;
        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        background:url(../images/button-2.png) repeat-x left -88px #e2e2e2;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #e2e2e2); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #e2e2e2); /* FF3.6 */
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #e2e2e2); /* IE10 */
        background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #e2e2e2); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background:         linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #e2e2e2);
    }
    .button-2:hover {
        background:url(../images/button-2.png) repeat-x left top #585858;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #727272, #585858); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #727272, #585858); /* FF3.6 */
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #727272, #585858); /* IE10 */
        background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #727272, #585858); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background:         linear-gradient(top, #727272, #585858);
        border-bottom-color:#585858;
        border-top-color:#727272;
        border-left-color:#6d6d6d;
        border-right-color:#606060;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .marker-1 {
        background:url(../images/marker-1.gif) left 3px no-repeat;
        padding:0 0 0 24px;
    }
    .marker-2 {
        background:url(../images/marker-2.gif) left 2px no-repeat;
        padding:0 0 0 24px;
    }
    /*********************************lists*************************************/
    .ul-1 {
        padding-left:6px;
        margin-bottom:12px;
    }
    .ul-1 li {
        font-size:14px;
        line-height:17px;
        background:url(../images/ul-1.png) left 8px no-repeat;
        padding:4px 0 5px 24px;
    }
    .ul-1 li a {
        color:#616161;
    }
    .ul-1 li a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .ul-2 li {
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:16px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:8px 0;
    }
    .ul-2 li a {
        color:#959595;
        background:url(../images/ul-2.png) left -91px no-repeat;
        padding-left:24px;
    }
    .ul-2 li a:hover {
        color:#3e3e3e;
        text-decoration:none;
        background-position:left 5px;
    }
    .ul-3 li {
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:18px;
        background:url(../images/ul-3.png) left 7px no-repeat;
        padding:4px 0 4px 30px;
    }
    .ul-3 li a {
        color:#959595;
    }
    .ul-3 li a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .ul-4 li {
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:16px;
        color:#959595;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
        padding:6px 0;
    }
    .ul-4 li a {
        color:#959595;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }
    .ul-4 li a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .ul-4 li span {
        display:block;
        float:right;
    }
    .ul-4 li strong {
        background:url(../images/ul-4.png) left 11px repeat-x;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
    }
    .dl-1 dt {
        font-size:15px;
        line-height:22px;
        color:#2b2b2b;
        margin-bottom:19px;
    }
    .dl-1 dd {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .dl-1 dd span {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:80px;
    }
    /*********************************fonts*************************************/

    .size-1 {font-size:24px; line-height:29px;}
    .size-2 {font-size:46px; line-height:56px;}
    .size-2r {
        font-size:46px;
        line-height:56px;
        color: #F00;
    }
    .size-2y {
        font-size:46px;
        line-height:56px;
        color: #FB040;
    }

    .size-3 {font-size:76px; line-height:92px;}
    .size-3b {
        font-size:76px;
        line-height:92px;
        color: #36F;
    }
    .size-4 {font-size:36px; line-height:44px;}
    .size-5 {font-size:15px; line-height:22px;}
    .size-6 {font-size:18px; line-height:22px;}
    .size-7 {font-size:32px; line-height:39px;}
    .size-8 {font-size:21px; line-height:26px;}

    .color-1 {color:#2b2b2b;}
    .color-2 {color:#fff;}
    .color-3 {color:#dedede;}
    .color-4 {color:#8d8d8d;}
    .color-5 {color:#434343;}
    .color-6 {color:#3e3e3e;}
    .color-7 {color:##3366FF;}

    /**************** "slideshow" ************/
    #slideshow {
        width:700px !important;
        height:270px !important;
        overflow:hidden !important;
        background:none !important;
    }
    #slideshow .wrapper {
        padding-top:76px;
        background:none !important;
    }
    #slideshow strong {
        letter-spacing:-3px;
        margin-left:-2px;
    }
    .cycle_wrap {
        background:none !important;
        position:relative;
    }
    .cycle_wrap #nav a {
        display:block;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
        background:url(../images/cycle.png) right top no-repeat;
    }
    .cycle_wrap #nav a.activeSlide,.cycle_wrap #nav a:hover {
        background-position:left top;
    }
    .cycle_wrap #nav a.activeSlide {
        cursor:default;
    }
    .cycle_wrap #nav {
        position:absolute;
        left:445px;
        top:315px;
        z-index:999;
    }
```

This much I know... It appears that this area seems to be the problem:

```
    .bg-3 
    {
        overflow: visible;
        width: 33%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 270px;
        background-image: url(http://www.webstertoolbox.com/skin/frontend/default/erglighting/images/bg-4.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

    .floatstop:after {
        clear: both;
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    :first-child + html .floatstop {
        min-height: 1px;
    }
    * html .floatstop {
        height: 1%;
    }
```

Any suggestions why this isn't working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definiing a height for .margin-bot  class also does the job (in my  firebug Lite/google-chrome/Ubuntu):

```
.margin-bot {
  margin-bottom:7px;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: That did it... I removed the display and float and added in your height and that aligned them all up. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the boxes.

I note that you seem to be a bit confused over what you're trying to do. Your definitions include `display:inline-block` AND `display:block`. Look over your CSS carefully and make sure it all makes sense.

Comment: I removed some of the code in the bg-3 and right below it. The area above that I said might be causing problems is what I removed. Because when I do use it the boxes link up on the top fine but the boxes are not inside the bordered line. I add vertical-align:top to the boxes and that didn't do anything. So I removed that to. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @Kolink (off topic) Congratulations for 100k rep! :D

Answer (score 0):

In

```
.bg-3 
    {
        overflow: visible;
        width: 33%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 270px;
        background-image: url(http://www.webstertoolbox.com/skin/frontend/default/erglighting/images/bg-4.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
```

Try with

```
.bg-3 
    {
        overflow: visible;
        width: 33%;
        display: inline-table;
        height: 270px;
        background-image: url(http://www.webstertoolbox.com/skin/frontend/default/erglighting/images/bg-4.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
```

Specifically changing the display to `inline-table`

Comment: when I apply your code it causes the three boxes to align but outside the border. It has to do with the display and float. When they are applied then the boxes appear outside the borders. Any other suggestions. Thank yoU!

Comment: @FrankG.
I am unsure of exactly you are trying to explain as I when I test it with Google Chrome dev-tools, it seems to work perfectly. Nothing else changes other than the alignment of the boxes.

Elaborate please?